# Build query in Faircom c-Tree Plus

Tags: c#, database, odbc

I have a Faircom c-tree database file (.dat & .idx).
I have connected it using ODBC Faircom Driver.

now I want to build queries on that database. actually i have already ready SQL version query but it is not working in c-tree database.

most of functions are not supported(like isnull,isnumeric,dateadd etc.)

help me to come out of this.

Comment: What's the command? Several of these are supported.

Comment: Connected C-Tree database through ODBC drivers.I am using ODBC Query Tool to work with queries. 

its not supporting general functions. for example,
    select top 5 * from TableName

then it shows 
    Error 0 42000 [FairCom][FairCom ODBC Driver 3.16.11.15]select top 5<< ??? >> * from MRRX99

Answer (score 0):

There is a developer's guide here for C#, as one of your tags is:[.Net Guide](https://docs.faircom.com/doc/ctreedn/#cover.htm)

As well as a specific citing of your read example here:
[C# Read Example](https://docs.faircom.com/doc/ctreedn/#42091.htm)

Citing the example from the above link, your read code would look something like this:

```
static void Initialize()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("INIT");
            try
            {
                // This section is only needed for the AppServer DLL model.
                bool AppServerModel = true;
                if (AppServerModel)
                {
                    // Set c-tree database engine configuration file name.
                    CTSession.SetConfigurationFile("ctsrvr.cfg");
                    // Start c-tree database engine.
                    CTSession.StartDatabaseEngine();
                }
                // allocate objects
                MySession = new CTSession(SESSION_TYPE.CTREE_SESSION);
                MyTable = new CTTable(MySession);
                MyRecord = new CTRecord(MyTable);
            }
            catch(CTException E)
            {
                Handle_Exception(E);
            }
            try
            {
                // connect to server
                Console.WriteLine("\tLogon to server...");
                MySession.Logon("FAIRCOMS", "", "");
            }
            catch(CTException E)
            {
                Handle_Exception(E);
            }
        }

static void Display_Records()
        {
            bool found;
            string custnumb;
            string custname;
            Console.Write("\tDisplay records...");
            try
            {
                // read first record
                found = MyRecord.First();
                while (found)
                {
                    custnumb = MyRecord.GetFieldAsString(0);
                    custname = MyRecord.GetFieldAsString(4);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\t\t{0,-8}{1,-20}", custnumb, custname);
                    // read next record
                    found = MyRecord.Next();
                }
            }
            catch(CTException E)
            {
                Handle_Exception(E);
            }
        }
```